# Bootstrap 4 loading error in console why?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, loading

I am trying to study bootstrap-4 and that's will work but  take the inspect element and show error in console like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at setTransitionEndSupport

[image]

Why this type error show when I am loading css file like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap-grid.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" type="text/css">
```

and js file are

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

any way to slove this issue ?  or loading problem !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load jquery first before bootstrap's js. And don't use minified, uncompressed file together. Use one of those.

css files like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sourcz/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" type="text/css">
```

js files like:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sourcz/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The grid and normal CSS + bundle and normal JS should **not** be combined also! I recommend that you remove the grid CSS and the normal JS. The bundle includes PopperJS, which is needed for some parts of Bootstrap.

Comment: @Klooven  why remove grid css  and normal js,, then work grid system

Comment: Check the docs. You should only have one type of CSS and JS: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/contents/#css-files